# Add self-signed certificates in Android TV

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-tv, mitmproxy

Anyone knows how to install a self-signed certificate into an Android Smart TV (Android 9)?

I need to set up a transparent proxy with mitmproxy to capture plaintext traffic. If I try so without putting the certificate into the TV it gives me this error:

`client handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy’s certificate`

since the CA is not trusted.

I am able to connect via ADB to the television but it seems that I do not have the right permissions to put files in directories. I've seen that some people suggest to root the television to be able to install it in a specific folder.

Anyone has some suggestions or has already done so?

Comment: I don't know how it is on Android TV but on regular Android device installing the mitmproxy root-ca certificate is useless as Android since Android 6 does by default ignore user installed certificates. Only if you modify the app-to-be-intercepted user installed certificates are used. Otherwise with root permissions it is also possible to install a new root-CA certificate as system certificate.